# Can only read one name from text file

Tags: file, text, fstream

I have a struct (RECORD) containing a name (char name[25]), age (int age), and gpa (float gpa). I'm trying to read data from this text file:

```css
Jacqueline Kennedy       33 3.5
Claudia Johnson          25 2.5
Pat Nixon                33 2.7
Rosalyn Carter           26 2.6
Nancy Reagan             19 3.5
Barbara Bush             33 3.4
Hillary Clinton          25 2.5
```

Each name in the file is 25 characters long (that is, the numbers are 25 characters to the right). I'm trying to copy this data into an array of RECORD a[7]. This is the code I have:

```css
fstream f;
f.open("data.txt", ios::in);
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
 f.get(a[i].name, 25); //reads the first 25 characters
 f >> a[i].age >> a[i].gpa;
}
f.close();
```

It only reads the first line of data, but nothing after. How do I make it continue to the rest of the lines?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would help. First you need to read the entire file in an array and convert it into a string array which has the string length you said 25 characters. Then you just have to iterate through that array to display it.

```
if(f.is_open())
{
//file opened successfully so we are here
cout << "File Opened successfully!!!. Reading data from file into array" << endl;
//this loop run until end of file (eof) does not occ
    while(!f.eof() && position < array_size)
    {
        f.get(array[position]); //reading one character from file to array
        position++;
    }
    array[position-1] = '\0'; //placing character array terminating character

cout << "Displaying Array..." << endl << endl;
//this loop display all the charaters in array till \0 
    for(int i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i];
       /*then you can divide the array in your desired length strings, which     here is: Jacqueline Kennedy       33 3.5
       Claudia Johnson          25 2.5
       Pat Nixon                33 2.7
       Rosalyn Carter           26 2.6
       Nancy Reagan             19 3.5
       Barbara Bush             33 3.4
       Hillary Clinton          25 2.5*/

    }
}
else //file could not be opened
{
    cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
}
```